# Should I incorporate information and suggestions posted as comments into my answer?

Tags: discussion

For example, several good comments were made on [my answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/133304/35141). In the interest of housekeeping, should I add them to my answer and provide attribution, then flag them for removal, or should I simply leave them as comments?

Answer (score 3):

Add them to the answer.  Comments are meant to be temporary.